# How to upgrade Joomla 2.5.28 to 3.3 manually?

Tags: upgrade

I have tried many many procedures but could not succeed migrating my Joomla 2.5.28 web site to 3.3.6.

Before migration:

1. Unistalled third party extensions which are not compatible with 3.3.6
2. Cleared cache
3. Got a backup

Then I set Joomla Update to "Short Term Support". No new notification came up to screen like in the videos on the web. I think this is because of Joomla 2.5.x is has been deprecated since 31.12.2014.

I do not know how to migrate now. Could that be because of I work on my local computer? Is there any possibility about that? Too silly but I think I should be obsessive.

I wish I had only a few web sites. Then I would upgrade them copying database records to fresh installations. But I have more than 100 web sites and no time. But I have to upgrade them for security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried purging the cache in the backend? Have a look through this list to see if there has been anything you've missed off: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

Comment: I did all of them.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/cmsupdate.html

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter whether you are upgrading your site on a local machine. As long as your Joomla! can access the internet and so grab the necessary upgrade files. It should tell you that an upgrade can be downloaded as soon as you enable 'Short term support' and then clear your cache and refresh the page.

Be careful: There are some caveats in upgrading, like the one with disabling or even renaming the remeber plugin!